# Family of types in type theory

Tags: type-theory, dependent-types

Can anyone simplify the meaning of families of types index by a type. It looks i get it but quite not understood it. What do you mean by a "family" ?

I understand index by a value (n length sequence) then what you mean by index by a type. Any example how you index by a type ? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the example of the dependent type of number sequences of length $n$. It might be defined like this in Coq:

```
  Inductive Sequence : nat -> Type :=
  | nil : Sequence O
  | cons : forall (n : nat), nat -> Sequence n -> Sequence (S n).
```

For every `n : nat` we have a type `Sequence n`. We say that `Sequence` is *indexed by `nat`* or that *`Sequence` depends on `nat`*. We could also say that `Sequence n` depends on the index `n`.

In any case, we are just discussing terminology here. The following are equiavalent ways of saying the same thing:

- Type $B$ depends on type $A$
- $B$ is a type family indexed by type $A$
- $B$ is a dependent type indexed by type $A$
- $B : A \to \mathsf{Type}$
- for $x : A$, $B(x)$ is a type
- $x : A \vdash B(x) \ \mathsf{type}$

The reason we use the word *family* is that in mathematics a collection of sets indexed by a set, $\lbrace A_i \rbrace_{i \in I}$, is called a family of sets. It corresponds to a dependent type $A$ indexed by a type $I$.

Comment: Some more terminology, for what it's worth. There is also a distinction between *parameterized* and *indexed* families of types. An excerpt from the [Agda reference manual](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=ReferenceManual.Data): *The difference between an index and a parameter is that the index need not be constant throughout the definition of the type.* The linked article has some examples illustrating the statement.

Comment: @AntonTrunov: it is worth pointing out that the index/parameter terminology applies specifically to *inductive* datatypes, not to general types. In terms of fixed points, it is the difference between defining a family of types $B : A \to \mathsf{Type}$ as $\mu B : \mathsf{Type} . \lambda x : A . \cdots$ or $\lambda x : A . \mu B : \mathsf{Type} . \cdots$